# how to use "windows" over "aggregation using groupby followed by join"?

Tags: pyspark, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe (`df`) with below structure:
`Grid_ID, Latitude, Longitude, DateTimeStamp`

Input:

```
Grid_ID    Latitude Longitude DateTimeStamp 
Grid_1     Lat1     Long1     2021-06-30 00:00:00
Grid_1     Lat1     Long1     2021-06-30 00:01:00
Grid_1     Lat1     Long1     2021-06-30 00:02:00
Grid_1     Lat2     Long2     2021-07-01 00:00:00
Grid_1     Lat2     Long2     2021-07-01 00:01:00
Grid_1     Lat2     Long2     2021-07-01 00:02:00
```

and Grid_ID has two sets of lat and long that are mutually exclusive based upon Date column. i.e. when Date <= 06/30/2021, Latitude/Longitude = Lat1/Long1 and
when Date > 06/30/2021, Latitude/Longitude = Lat2/Long2, respectively

I need to create new columns (Corrected_Lat and Corrected_Long) and assign Lat2/Long2

I am using groupBy and agg as below to do the above:

```
df_dated = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date("DateTimeStamp")) \
                             .filter(F.col("date") == "2021-07-01") \
                             .groupBy("Grid_ID") \
             .agg(F.collect_set("Latitude").getItem(0).cast("float").alias("corrected_lat"),
                  F.collect_set("Longitude").getItem(0).cast("float").alias("corrected_long")) \
             .withColumnRenamed("Grid_ID", "Grid_ID_dated") \
             .select("Grid_ID_dated", "corrected_lat", "corrected_long")
df_final = df.join(df_dated, on=[df.Grid_ID == df_dated.Grid_ID_dated],
                   how="inner") \
             .select(*df.columns, "corrected_lat", "corrected_long")
```

Output:

```
Grid_ID    Latitude Longitude DateTimeStamp        corrected_lat   corrected_long
Grid_1     Lat1     Long1     2021-06-30 00:00:00  Lat2            Long2
Grid_1     Lat1     Long1     2021-06-30 00:01:00  Lat2            Long2
Grid_1     Lat1     Long1     2021-06-30 00:02:00  Lat2            Long2
Grid_1     Lat2     Long2     2021-07-01 00:00:00  Lat2            Long2
Grid_1     Lat2     Long2     2021-07-01 00:01:00  Lat2            Long2
Grid_1     Lat2     Long2     2021-07-01 00:02:00  Lat2            Long2
```

But I am wondering if windows function can be used here and would it be faster than first approach using groupBy and agg?

Any other approach that is faster is certainly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add examples of input and output? Why are you filtering this specific date `filter(F.col("date") == "2021-07-01")`?

Comment: @bzu out of the two set of coordinates for each Grid_ID, I need to keep the 2nd set (Lat2/Long2). Second set of coordinates are available for timestamps on or after 2021-07-01. Before this date, the Gird_ID has former set of coordinates (Lat1/Long1)

Comment: So basically you want to keep 1 line per Grid_ID with date >= 2021-07-01? Are Lat2/Long2 in all rows the same for each Grid_ID?

Comment: yes, there are two sets of lat/long for each grid_id currently but final output should have the one set of lat long (latter set i.e. Lat2/Long2) for each grid id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will apply the latest Latitude/Longitude value to all rows (per Grid_ID):

```
w = (
    Window.partitionBy('Grid_ID')
    .orderBy("DateTimeStamp")
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
)
df_final = (
    df.withColumn("date", F.to_date("DateTimeStamp"))
    .select(*df.columns,
            F.last('Latitude').over(w).alias('corrected_lat'),
            F.last('Longitude').over(w).alias('corrected_long'),
            )
)
```

Comment: shouldn't the orderBy("DateTimeStamp") be orderBy("date") ?

Comment: You could also use `"date"`. In any case the window will be sorted and with `last()` you can get the most recent value. Does this work for you?

Comment: it certainly did. I wasnt aware of rowsBetween with options you pointed me to.

Would you also happen to know the performance comparison between use of "windows" and "aggregation using groupby", i.e. whether one is faster in spark over other (1) universally (2) situation dependent

Comment: I don't know if there is a general answer to this. I would look at `df_final.explain()` and try to get any hints from there or do a couple of benchmarks on a subset of input data.